# I want to connect two of my computers using a cable, which kind of cable I will need?

Tags: networking

I want to connect two of my computers using a cable, both RJ45 Ports in both computers are occupied with the ethernet cables, I heard of USB Bridge Cable but I am not finding it in India, any other cables present to connect both computers directly to transfer data between them directly?

Comment: What kind of data will you be copying between them? If both of the network jacks are in use, that assumes they are networked and if they're on the same network you can just move files that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directly connect MacBook to Linux desktop via ethernet for fast SSH?](https://superuser.com/questions/842924/directly-connect-macbook-to-linux-desktop-via-ethernet-for-fast-ssh)

Comment: A *USB Bridge Cable* wouldn’t be helpful with an RJ45 port.  Why would you not just use a router and enable file sharing?  Of course how that’s accomplished is 100% depends on what operating system your using.

Answer (score 1):

You could *add* an extra RJ45 port:

- If they are laptops, you can buy two USB Ethernet adapters/dongles, one for each computer, and connect them together using a short Ethernet cable.

  (I think that's basically what the "USB bridge cables" do in their internal circuitry anyway.)
- If they are desktop computers, buy an Ethernet card for PCI or PCI-Express slots.
- (If they're *very old* laptops with no USB, there are of course Ethernet PCMCIA cards too.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the product which is available to buy,

1) [Product 1](https://www.amazon.in/GearMo-Driverless-Transfer-Cable-Windows/dp/B004GIGNVC) - Transfer Files and Data from one PC directly to another PC

For product information visit - 
[https://www.amazon.com/GearMo-Driverless-Transfer-Cable-Windows/dp/B004GIGNVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004GIGNVC)

Comment: Most PC USB controllers (pre-TypeC) only support host mode, and only one end of a USB connection can be the host, so such cables won't be able to establish any connection (and I wouldn't be surprised if they just fried the port). You need an active cable which presents a device to both sides.